# About Weyl superconductors and fractionalized Weyl semimetals

Tags: topological-order, topological-insulators, majorana-fermions, topological-phase

Recently, the experimental observations of Weyl fermion semi-metal have been made. Weyl fermion becomes very hot in condensed matter physics. I am confused about the Weyl superconductors and fractionalized Weyl semi-metals:

1. pedagogical introduction of the [Weyl superconductor](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.86.054504), what are the common and different characteristic, compared with topological superconductor?
2. what is the [fractionalized Weyl semimetals](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921452615301186)? what are the common and different characterist, compared with three fractional topological insulator?